# About lists entries and labels

Tags: python, list, loops, tkinter, label

Hi so i have 3 lists: list1 list2 and list3 in tkinter window
and i would like to do it like this:

[image]

I would like that every time the user pressing "enter" after he finished entry writing the label T1 would change to T2 and the entry will be cleaned from text 
when the user reached T5 the Label SUB1 will be change to SUB2 and after the user reached T10 the Label SUB2 will be changed to SUB3 and for each value in list2 will be displayed also 1 value from list3 thank you guys I hope that i asked the question well and to the point 
this is my code that I tried to display it but not even print function worked when I pressed ENTER on my entry:

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import ttk
import json 
from collections import defaultdict
import pickle

class Language(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

          tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
          frame = tk.Frame(self,)
          list1 = ["SUB1","SUB2","SUB3"]
          list2 = [['T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4'], ['T5', 'T6', 'T7', 'T8', 'T9'], 
                  ['T10', 'T11', 'T12', 'T13', 'T14', 'T15', 'T16', 'T17']]

          list3 = ['rocket', 'file', 'meth', 'pink', 'jelly', 'say', 'east',  'west']

          if i > len(list1):
              print("the end")
          else:
              for u in range(len(list1)):

                  label_sub = tk.Label(self, text=str(list1[i]) + ":",                                                      bg="green", )
                  label_sub.place(x=100, y=150)
              for b in range(len(list[u])):

                  def add(n):
                      n += 1
                      return n

                  if j > len(list2[b]):
                      i += 1 
                  else:
                      label_time = tk.Label(self, text=str(list2[b][add(j)]) +                                                      ":", bg="green", )
                      label_time.place(x=0, y=200)
                      label_word = tk.Label(self, text=str(list3[b]), 
                                                     bg="green", )
                      label_word.place(x=150, y=250)

                      q_entry = tk.Entry(self)
                      q_entry.bind('<Return>', print("something"))
                      q_entry.place(x=300, y=200)

root = Language() 
root.geometry("612x417") 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your cod is not [mcve], strip it down to **one** problem.

Comment: Dude is spent 30 min to write this its the third time i ask a question and it is still wrong

Comment: OK THANKS any way

Comment: Read [tkinter-events-and-bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) to understand how your `print("something")` should be to implemented. Use `__init__` **only** to layout your widgets as like in your image.